# Refactoring PostgreSQL SProcs

Tags: postgresql, refactoring, user-defined-functions

with a moderate PostgreSQL installation we accumulated quite a few stored procedures/functions and types.

Now in the lowest level composite type (i.e. 3 types are built with it and a myriad functions reference any of those types) one element of the type is of **wrong type** (i.e. smallint instead of bigint), thus handling it is identical, only the range is different.

1. How do I know all types depending on
   a type (pg_catalog.pg_type seems
   insufficient)?
2. How can I know all
   functions depending on a type (as
   arguments and locally scoped vars)?
3. Can I refactore a composite type
   (maybe change smallint to bigint)
   without dropping/rebuilding every
   single function depending on it?
4. Is there any kind of
   automation/tool/best practice for
   such a refactoring?

I know its 4 questions in one, but atm this is kind of frustrating and any help would be appreciated!
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system catalogue "pg_depend" contains some useful dependency information. You can find objects depending on particular types a bit like this:

```
select * from pg_depend where refclassid = 'pg_type'::regclass
    and refobjid = 'information_schema.sql_identifier'::regtype;
```

This finds objects dependent on the "information_schema.sql_identifier" type. In the result, classid is the OID of a catalogue- for instance, for a column depending on a user type, classid is 'pg_class'::regclass, objid is the OID of the pg_class row, and objsubid is the attnum value from pg_attribute, so for this case you can format the results like this:

```
select objid::regclass, attname from pg_depend
    join pg_attribute on pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_depend.objid and pg_attribute.attnum = pg_depend.objsubid
where refclassid = 'pg_type'::regclass and refobjid = 'information_schema.sql_identifier'::regtype
    and classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
limit 10
```

So in pg_depend, `(classid,objid,objsubid)` describe some object that depends on the object described by `(refclassid,refobjid)`.

Comment: This works fabulous, but does only give me the type hierarchy itself, right? This does not expand to dependent functions?

Comment: It will give you which functions depend on which user types (refclassid = 'pg_proc'::regclass), but won't tell you which functions call which other functions, no. I suspect it won't go down into the implementation of the function to see if you're using a user type as a local variable, either; I suspect that this information is all managed by the language agnostic part of PostgreSQL which wouldn't see that.

Comment: I see, ill try to see if I can find out more, as refactoring a plpsql code base should be an encountered problem, and there should be some solution or tool support out there for this.

Comment: its pretty difficult to find anything on preventing drop cascades and getting reliable information on the cascades, which are saved into pg_depend as shown above, there also seems to be almost no tool support, so lets close this for now